# Order Spark SQL Dataframe with nested values / complex data types

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My goal is to collect an ordered list of nested values. It should be ordered based on an element in the nested list. I tried out different approaches but have concerns in terms of performance and correctness.

**Order globally**

```scala
case class Payment(Id: String, Date: String, Paid: Double)

val payments = Seq(
  Payment("mk", "10:00 AM", 8.6D),
  Payment("mk", "06:00 AM", 12.6D),
  Payment("yc", "07:00 AM", 16.6D),
  Payment("yc", "09:00 AM", 2.6D),
  Payment("mk", "11:00 AM", 5.6D)
)
val df = spark.createDataFrame(payments)

// order globally
df.orderBy(col("Paid").desc)
  .groupBy(col("Id"))
  .agg(
    collect_list(struct(col("Date"), col("Paid"))).as("UserPayments")
  )
  .withColumn("LargestPayment", col("UserPayments")(0).getField("Paid"))
  .withColumn("LargestPaymentDate", col("UserPayments")(0).getField("Date"))
  .show(false)

+---+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------------+
|Id |UserPayments                                     |LargestPayment|LargestPaymentDate|
+---+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------------+
|yc |[[07:00 AM,16.6], [09:00 AM,2.6]]                |16.6          |07:00 AM          |
|mk |[[06:00 AM,12.6], [10:00 AM,8.6], [11:00 AM,5.6]]|12.6          |06:00 AM          |
+---+-------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------------+
```

This is a naive and straight-forward approach, but I have concerns in terms of correctness. Will the list really be ordered globally or only within a partition?

**Window function**

```scala
// use Window
val window = Window.partitionBy(col("Id")).orderBy(col("Paid").desc)
df.withColumn("rank", rank().over(window))
  .groupBy(col("Id"))
  .agg(
    collect_list(struct(col("rank"), col("Date"), col("Paid"))).as("UserPayments")
  )
  .withColumn("LargestPayment", col("UserPayments")(0).getField("Paid"))
  .withColumn("LargestPaymentDate", col("UserPayments")(0).getField("Date"))
  .show(false)

+---+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------------+
|Id |UserPayments                                           |LargestPayment|LargestPaymentDate|
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------------+
|yc |[[1,07:00 AM,16.6], [2,09:00 AM,2.6]]                  |16.6          |07:00 AM          |
|mk |[[1,06:00 AM,12.6], [2,10:00 AM,8.6], [3,11:00 AM,5.6]]|12.6          |06:00 AM          |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------------+
```

This should work or do I miss something?

**Order in UDF on-the-fly**

```scala
// order in UDF
val largestPaymentDate = udf((lr: Seq[Row]) => {
  lr.max(Ordering.by((l: Row) => l.getAs[Double]("Paid"))).getAs[String]("Date")
})

df.groupBy(col("Id"))
  .agg(
    collect_list(struct(col("Date"), col("Paid"))).as("UserPayments")
  )
  .withColumn("LargestPaymentDate", largestPaymentDate(col("UserPayments")))
  .show(false)

+---+-------------------------------------------------+------------------+
|Id |UserPayments                                     |LargestPaymentDate|
+---+-------------------------------------------------+------------------+
|yc |[[07:00 AM,16.6], [09:00 AM,2.6]]                |07:00 AM          |
|mk |[[10:00 AM,8.6], [06:00 AM,12.6], [11:00 AM,5.6]]|06:00 AM          |
+---+-------------------------------------------------+------------------+
```

I guess nothing to complain here in terms of correctness. But for the following operations, I'd prefer that the list is ordered and I don't have to do every time explicitly.

I tried to write a UDF which takes the list as an input and returns the ordered list - but returning a list was too painful and I gave it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd reverse the order of the `struct` and aggregate with `max`:

```
val result = df
  .groupBy(col("Id"))
  .agg(
    collect_list(struct(col("Date"), col("Paid"))) as "UserPayments",
    max(struct(col("Paid"), col("Date"))) as "MaxPayment"
  )

result.show
// +---+--------------------+---------------+ 
// | Id|        UserPayments|     MaxPayment|
// +---+--------------------+---------------+
// | yc|[[07:00 AM,16.6],...|[16.6,07:00 AM]|
// | mk|[[10:00 AM,8.6], ...|[12.6,06:00 AM]|
// +---+--------------------+---------------+
```

You can later  flatten the `struct`:

```
result.select($"id", $"UserPayments", $"MaxPayment.*").show
// +---+--------------------+----+--------+
// | id|        UserPayments|Paid|    Date|
// +---+--------------------+----+--------+
// | yc|[[07:00 AM,16.6],...|16.6|07:00 AM|
// | mk|[[10:00 AM,8.6], ...|12.6|06:00 AM|
// +---+--------------------+----+--------+
```

Same way you can `sort_array` of reordered structs

```
df
  .groupBy(col("Id"))
  .agg(
    sort_array(collect_list(struct(col("Paid"), col("Date")))) as "UserPayments"
  )
  .show(false)
// +---+-------------------------------------------------+
// |Id |UserPayments                                     |
// +---+-------------------------------------------------+
// |yc |[[2.6,09:00 AM], [16.6,07:00 AM]]                |
// |mk |[[5.6,11:00 AM], [8.6,10:00 AM], [12.6,06:00 AM]]|
// +---+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Finally:

> This is a naive and straight-forward approach, but I have concerns in terms of correctness. Will the list really be ordered globally or only within a partition?

Data will be ordered globally, but the order will be destroyed by `groupBy` so this is is not a solution, and can work only accidentally.

`repartition` (by `id`) and `sortWithinPartitions` (by `id` and `Paid`) should be reliable replacement.

Comment: keep on going ;) I wasn't aware that `sort_array` works on a list of nested values.